# What kind of dialog box is this? How can I interact with it using Puppeteer?

Tags: node.js, google-chrome, puppeteer

[image]

I'm using puppeteer to run a Google Chrome browser(I've tried with Chromium as well), to generate a PDF and then I'm using the URL to send the PDF to some other software. I'm getting stuck at this dialog box of sorts.

I assumed it was a normal dialog box and have tried the usual method of hitting the "confirm" button. I can't seem to get it to work. I'm unable to show you the URL I am using the get this to show up, as it is sensitive.

As I mentioned, page.on() doesn't seem to catch the box.

````
    const newP = await browser.newPage();
    newP.on('dialog', async dialog => {
            console.log(dialog.message());
            console.log(dialog.accept());
    });
    await newP.goto(`exampleURL`);```
````

Comment: Did you manage to solve this? Setting a default program for me doesn't work - it always needs that dialog clicked.

Answer (score 0):

This modal is not accessible from the DOM/Page.
Your browser seem to redirect opening PDF files to local software on your machine.
Solution: try to disconnecting or remove default program / software.

Windows:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4028161/windows-10-change-default-programs

Mac:
https://www.macworld.co.uk/how-to/mac-software/change-default-apps-mac-3656510/